# Does BigTable bill by hour if CPU activity is idle?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I would expect Storage/Hr, but am curious if the BigTable instance clusters will dip in price if activity is idle for long stretches.

(if not, that's a bummer)

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [pricing docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing), Cloud Bigtable will charge for the number of nodes in your instance, the data storage and the network bandwidth. Bigtable provides dedicated resources for your cluster, which are not shared across multiple clusters, so an idle cluster's CPU cannot be reused for another cluster, so the price remains constant.

Furthermore, Bigtable requires to have at least 3 nodes in production instance (development instance is equivalent to a single node). Therefore, you will be charged at least for 3 nodes even your instance doesn’t receive any data.

[Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview) is good for applications that need very high throughput and scalability for non-structured data. If your application does not need these properties, you may like to have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) for other storage options.

Comment: Also: if you expect your Bigtable instance to be idle for a while, you can temporarily shrink your cluster until it is needed again (subject to 3 node minimum and per-node storage limits: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#storage-per-node)